# How can I make row to a column in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2, pivot

I have table A, below, where for each unique id, there are two codes with some value.

```
Name      Value

1         x
2         y
3         z
```

I want B, with format as below:

```
x    y     z

1    2     3
```

Comment: Look here: https://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot

Comment: "_for each unique id, there are two codes with some value_"? Can't you adjust the sample data to include such values? (Now I see, there's also an id column?)

Comment: no there is none